# Laravel Eloquent - How to query all car models of given year where make is given?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have these tables: `Models`, `Year` and `Model_Year`. The `Model` table has a `make_id` column referencing an `id` in `Make` table.

In my model I have defined a *belongsToMany* relationship between `Model` and `Year`.

This is what am doing so far in controller:

```
public function getModels() {
  $year = Year::findOrFail(1);
  $make = Vmake::findOrFail(1);
  $models = $year->model->pluck('name','id');

  return response()->json($models);
}
```

This returns all models of year with `id` 1.

How do I add a query to get only models where `make_id` = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a simple solution for this. You just need to change function as I given below

```
public function getModels() {
  $year = Year::findOrFail(1);
  $make = Vmake::findOrFail(1);
  $models = $year->model()
                ->where('make_id', 1)
                ->pluck('name','id');

  return response()->json($models);
}
```

above is the changed code. Try and let me know if that not works for you.

Comment: @SamN could you please mark check to verify this answer and also upvote my answer. It will be very appreciated.